# Arduino Mega 2560 with SIM808 module - Incomplete SMS response

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, gsm

I have this code to read a SMS:

```
String read_SMS(int index)
{
  Serial.println("--START READ SMS POSITION" + String(index) + "--");
  delay(400);
  sendATcommand("AT+CMGF=1", "OK", 1000);    // sets the SMS mode to text
  delay(2000);
  String tmp;
  tmp = readATcommand("AT+CMGR=1", 4000);
  Serial.println("Content: " + tmp);
  Serial.println("--END READ SMS POSITION" + String(index) + "--");
}

String readATcommand(String ATcommand, unsigned int timeout)
{
  char response[800];
  unsigned long previous;
  memset(response, '\0', 800);    // Initialice the string

  int x = 0;

  GSMSerial.println(ATcommand);
  delay(3000);
  previous = millis();
  do {
    if (GSMSerial.available() > 0) {
      response[x] = GSMSerial.read();
      x++;
    }
  } while ((millis() - previous) < timeout);   // Waits for the asnwer with time out

  return (String) response;
}

// sending AT commands to the Sim808 module
int8_t sendATcommand(String ATcommand, char* expected_answer, unsigned int timeout) {

  uint8_t x = 0, answer = 0;
  char response[200];
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 200);    // Initialice the string

  delay(100);

  // Clean the input buffer
  while (GSMSerial.available() > 0 ) GSMSerial.read();

  if (ATcommand[0] != '\0') {
    // Send the AT command
    GSMSerial.println(ATcommand);
    //Serial.print(F("AT Command: "));
    //Serial.println(ATcommand);
  }

  // Waiting for the answer
  x = 0;
  previous = millis();

  do {

    // if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the asnwer
    if (GSMSerial.available() > 0) {

      response[x] = GSMSerial.read();
      x++;
      // check if the desired answer (OK) is in the response of the module
      if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL) {
        answer = 1;
      }
    }

  } while ((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < timeout));   // Waits for the asnwer with time out

  //Serial.println(F("START RESPONSE:"));
  //Serial.println(response);
  //Serial.println(F("END RESPONSE"));
  //if (answer == 0) {
  //  Serial.println("Could not get the expected answer!");
  //}
  //else {
  //  Serial.println("Found expected answer!");
  //}

  return answer;
}
```

What can be wrong in the readATcommand function as it replies with an incomplete response:

```
--START READ SMS POSITION1--
Content: 
AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","+407245402XX","","17/06/29,10:
--END READ SMS POSITION1--
```

But, when I run it from a terminal, the AT+CMGR=1 replies with:

```
AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","+40724540234","","17/06/29,10:03:06+12"
Salut

OK
```

As you can see the message body is not there + the time of the SMS is also incomplete.

Thank you!

Comment: What is `GSMSerial`?

Comment: @Majenko #define GSMSerial Serial3

Comment: My guess is that your gratuitous use of the `delay()` function is making the serial buffer overflow. There is *never* any call to use `delay()` when reading from serial. The AT protocol has proper handshaking signals that you should use, such as looking for "OK". There is no need to `delay()` while waiting for them, that's just silly.

Comment: Works now. At first I got to reply so I put the delays. After the delays I got the partial messages. Now without any delays .. I get the full messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delay.

In the three seconds that you wait between sending the AT command and reading the response the entire response has arrived and been placed in the serial RX buffer - which has overflowed because there's more than 64 bytes in the response. So you lose data.

You should never use `delay()` when reading from serial, it's dangerous (as you see).

Instead you should be just immediately reading until you see the correct response from the command you sent - which will either be "OK" or "ERROR". Everything before that is the content of the response to your command.